# Starting with Liferay and a bit overwhelmed with how to begin

Tags: java, xcode, themes, liferay

Hello I would like to start developing a lifeRay theme and am a little bit lost!

I am a Mac user and i have installed liferay and also Xcode but i am not clear how to begin.

I have downloaded the SDK for liferay but i do not understand how to install it or use it for that matter, so questions:

Is Xcode an appropriate development environment to work with or is something else a little easier to get on with?

Does Xcode build in the same way ANT does?

How do i install the SDK? Do i just drop it into Tomcat and away i go?

Yes i am very new to all this!! I am not actually sure if i am asking the right questions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just responded to a similar question (more detail on the theme part) .... basically, you need to use the terminal to use most of the SDK functionality.

if you're just developing a theme, you'll need to have the sdk and one of the server bundles downloaded.  put them in the same folder so you end up with something like

```
liferay/

liferay/tomcat (holding the tomcat bundle)

liferay/plugins (holding the plugin sdk)

liferay/deploy
```

then configure the .properties file .... create a file in the plugins folder and name it

build.[YOURNAME].properties ....

run this in the terminal window ... note the backtics aren't apos.

```
touch build.`whoami`.properties
```

edit the file and add these lines ...

app.server.dir=${project.dir}/../tomcat
auto.deploy.dir=${project.dir}/../deploy

then in the tomcat folder edit

```
tomcat/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/classes/portal-ext.properties
```

and edit / add the following line

```
 resource.repositories.root=/path/to/liferay
 auto.deploy.dest.dir=/path/to/liferay/deploy
```

.... to start the server change to the main folder and enter

```
tomcat/bin/startup.sh
```

you can watch the server's log by typing

```
tail -f tomcat/logs/catalina.out
```

Check my other post for all the CSS and THEME stuff ....

[Need to change template styles in Liferay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2080314/need-to-change-template-styles-in-liferay/2250275#2250275)

Answer (score 1):

Until two minutes ago, I had never heard of this software. But does it seem silly to start with the [Liferay Quick Start Guide](http://docs.liferay.com/portal/5.1/official/liferay-quick-start-guide-5.1.pdf)?

Comment: No it seems perfectly reasnoble to me: these are the questions i have that arise after i have RTFM :)

Answer (score 1):

Have you read the Liferay documentation on creating themes such as http://content.liferay.com/document/Liferay%20Themes.pdf

Do you have experience working with Java web apps in XCode? If not I'd try something like Eclipse or Netbeans that is more widely used.

Comment: hi yes i have, i was asking some specific questions about whther Xcide is appropriate, how xcode compiles and how to install the SDK

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question (from 2009) but I wanted to add in case someone is struggling with the same thing in **Liferay 6**.

You can actually develop a theme very *easily* by just going into the deploy directory:
`/deploy/`

Once in there, look for the default `seven-cogs-theme.war` folder.  What I did was initially copy & paste that folder to my desktop (or any dev location) to edit.  I modified the XML files using **Notepad++** to reflect my theme name (as well as renaming the directory).

You can then modify the theme to how you see fit (velocity templates / css / images / javascript includes / etc).

You can develop the theme LIVE on Liferay 6 (F5 to refresh and view changes), you would have to setup your portal to enable developer mode (disables js minimizer / css caching / minizers / image caching / etc).

Each of those pieces you can find by doing a search (developer mode for portal etc;).

Overall you can work with Liferay to modify things to your liking.

I am currently using Liferay with Coldfusion 9 for portlet development. Hope that helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

For your IDE, take a look at [Liferay IDE](http://www.liferay.com/community/liferay-projects/liferay-ide/overview).

Liferay IDE is a set of Eclipse plugins that make it much easier to create, build and deploy Liferay plugins such as portlets and themes.

There are two versions of this software:  Liferay IDE and Liferay Developer Studio.  The former is free and community-supported, while the latter is closed-source and only provided to Liferay EE customers.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this reference:
http://www.liferay.com/web/satyaranjan/blog/-/blogs/portal-pack-:-write-database-portlet-using-service-builder-plug-in

"The service builder framework in Liferay represents the database layer and all the interactions with database are done through service builder infrastructure. So in this blog, I will explain how you can use service builder framework inside your custom portlet using NetBeans 6.5 & Portal Pack 3.0. To use service builder framework, you first need to create a service xml and then generate the required code. The Portal Pack here helps you by providing a nice GUI editor for service.xml file where you can define the entities or database structures and from the same GUI you can generate the services code which can be used inside your portlet."